# Проверка URL на jQuery с условием для разных страниц

Tags: php, jquery

Всем привет! Делаю задачу на WP, сайт многоязычный, на каждой странице должны выводиться иконки соц.сетей, в 2х исполнениях:

1) все соц.сети (на русских)

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function() {  if (window.pluso)if (typeof window.pluso.start == "function") return;  if (window.ifpluso==undefined) { window.ifpluso = 1;    var d = document, s = d.createElement('script'), g = 'getElementsByTagName';    s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.charset='UTF-8'; s.async = true;    s.src = ('https:' == window.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http')  + '://share.pluso.ru/pluso-like.js';    var h=d[g]('body')[0];    h.appendChild(s);  }})();</script><div class="pluso" data-background="transparent" data-options="small,square,line,horizontal,nocounter,theme=08" data-services="vkontakte,odnoklassniki,facebook,twitter,google"></div>'
```

2) все соц.сети без ВК и Одноклассников (на английских)

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function() {  if (window.pluso)if (typeof window.pluso.start == "function") return;  if (window.ifpluso==undefined) { window.ifpluso = 1;    var d = document, s = d.createElement('script'), g = 'getElementsByTagName';    s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.charset='UTF-8'; s.async = true;    s.src = ('https:' == window.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http')  + '://share.pluso.ru/pluso-like.js';    var h=d[g]('body')[0];    h.appendChild(s);  }})();</script><div class="pluso" data-background="transparent" data-options="small,square,line,horizontal,nocounter,theme=08" data-services="facebook,linkedin,twitter,google"></div>
```

Подскажите пож как это можно сделать на jQuery с условием, которое будет срабатывать на URL, в котором есть en и ru?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался!
Привожу код в двух вариантах, т.к. jQuery не было и чтоб не было конфликтов не подключал, сам код(jQuery(comment) и чистый JS):

```
//    $(document).ready(function() 

{
        var str = window.location.href;
        if (str.indexOf('/ru/') != -1) {

            var russ = document.querySelector("#rus");
            russ.setAttribute('style','visibility: visible');
        };

        if (str.indexOf('/en/') != -1) {

            var enn = document.querySelector("#en");
            enn.setAttribute('style','visibility: visible');
        };

        if (str.indexOf('/es/') != -1) {

            var ess = document.querySelector("#es");
            ess.setAttribute('style','visibility: visible');
        };

          if (str.indexOf('/ru/') != -1) {

//            $("#rus").css('visibility', 'visible');
//            $("#en").css(['visibility', "hidden"]);
//            $("#es").css(['visibility', "hidden"]);
//            console.log(333);
//
//        if (str.indexOf('/en/') != -1) {
//
//            $("#rus").css('display', "hidden");
//            $("#en").css('display', "visible");
//            $("#es").css('display', "hidden");
//
//       if (str.indexOf('/es/') != -1) {
//
//            $("#rus").css('display', "hidden");
//            $("#en").css('display', "hidden");
//            $("#es").css('display', "visible");
//        };
//    }
```

Comment: не очень хорошее решение, если в url будет вхождение всех трех, причем в любом месте url, то видимыми станут все три блока

Comment: @Grundy сайт простенький, так что для текущей задачи подходит, если есть другие варианты, пишите, с радостью посмотрю альтернативу.

Comment: а, не увидел, что обычный indexOf, тогда нормально

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо! Я только учусь!)